# linux dlopen : how to make loading lib manager

Tags: c++, linux, dlopen

I have the same code compiled with different arch options (FMV does not work as the functions return sse and i can't change "default" to something with sse)
How can i make a meta-library that at load time checks the cpu capability and load the corresponding lib? (without any dlsym machinery)?

Comment: Define "different arches". Linux distributions use a multi-lib layout, where 64 bit libraries exist in /lib64, and 32 bit libraries exist in /lib. Simply by installing the appopriate libraries into the appropriate directory, with the same filename, and using dlopen() normally, will open the correct library.

Comment: i said "arch options" ;) in my case they are : -msse, -mavx ..etc...

Comment: Your question is really how to choose the appropriate arch option. Once that's done, loading the right library is straightforward. You can simply look in /proc/cpuinfo.

Comment: not determination of cpu capabilities is my problem  (cpuid FTW) but manipulation of dlopen : the presence of symbols is transparent? if i link with manager lib then i have to import all symbols .. is it possible to not import them?

Comment: dlopen opens the library you specify. Specify the correct library, based on the cpu capabilities, and open it. Your question is unclear.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I think OP wants proper library to be loaded by the ELF interpreter at program startup.

Comment: Exact.... well, i might scrap the idea and do a symlink when the rpm is installed....

Comment: Ok, well there's nothing in Linux's dlopen interface to automatically choose shared objects based on the CPU feature set. You have to handle it yourself. All of its functionality is documented in its man page. If it's not there it does not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to achieve what you want is to link against dummy wrapper library which checks CPU capabilities at startup, loads matching shared library and then forwards all function calls to their implementations in this shared library.

Such dummy library may be implemented by hand or generated via custom script. Or you can use [Implib.so](https://github.com/yugr/Implib.so) to generate it automatically:

```
$ implib-gen.py --dlopen-callback=load_mylib mylib_avx.so
```

You'll need to implement `load_mylib` (to analyze CPUID and `dlopen` appropriate implementation) and link your app with generated files.